# %%Errorlevel%% still turns to 0 even with extra % when using directors

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel

Basically I made a program in batch that creates a program that lets to customize the file name and keybinds for starting an incognito chrome window, and then closing it, but the keybinds use `%errorlevel%`, but when rewriting the information it turns to 0, I know a solution to fixing that once, but I need to do it twice.

I don't have much programming skills.

Also I could not figure out is it possible to close specifically the incognito window. Is there a way?

The code

Everything else works fine except the errorlevel lines, (but I thought i will provide everything tho)

```
echo @echo off  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set Closer= 1   >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set CloseBatch= 10  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo Title Module Configuration   >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo color 80  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo Module configuration  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo.  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set /p selectName= Select the name of the IncognitoModule: >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo cls  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo Module configuration  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo.  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set /p keybindStart= Select the letter that will start incognito mode (CHROME): >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo cls  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo Module configuration  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo.  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set /p keybindClose= Select the letter that will close CHROME: >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo :Closerino  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo cls  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo Module configuration  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo.  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set /p CloseBatch= Select do you want the module to close after the chrome termination (Y / N){default NO}: >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo if %%CloseBatch%% == 10 goto Closerino  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo if %%CloseBatch%% == Y goto YES  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo if %%CloseBatch%% == N goto NO  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo goto Closerino  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
 
echo :YES  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set Closer= 2  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo :NO  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo set Closer= 1  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo cls  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo You selected the name %%selectName%%  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo You selected the Keybind to start incognito mode %%keybindStart%%  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo You selected the Keybind to close chrome %%keybindClose%%  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo echo @echo off ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo :back ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo Title %%selectName%% ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo choice /c %%keybindStart%%%%keybindClose%% /n >> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo if %%errorlevel%%==1 goto Start ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo if %%errorlevel%%==2 goto Close ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo echo :Start ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo start chrome --new-window --incognito "www.google.com" ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo echo You started new Incognito window ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo ping -n 3 127.0.0.1^>nul ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo goto back ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo echo :Close ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo taskkill /f /im chrome.exe ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo echo if %%Closer%% == 1 goto back >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat

echo echo if %%Closer%% == 2 goto killeroni >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo :killeroni >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo taskkill cmd.exe >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
echo echo exit >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat
```

Comment: `%%%%errorlevel%%%%`

Comment: It is not needed whatsoever, you just need `echo echo if errorlevel 2 goto Close ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat`, and delete both of these lines: `echo echo if %%errorlevel%%==1 goto Start ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat` and 
`echo echo :Start ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat`

Comment: You also have a typo here, `echo echo choice /c %%keybindStart%%%%keybindClose%% /n >> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat`, which I assume should be `echo echo choice /c %%keybindStart%%%%keybindClose%% /n ^>^> %%selectName%%.bat  >> TempIncognitoCreator.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are double nesting, you need to double escape, so for your specific question, I'd advise that you need to use four percent characters per side, i.e. `%%%%errorlevel%%%%`. Essentially, you'd escape the first `%` with another for the first nesting, `%%`, then do the same for the next nesting, `%%%%`.

As an addition to the answer above, and to supplement my comments, here's an idea of how I'd suggest you structure your script. *I find this easier to read, and maintain, as well as reducing your code significantly*.

```batch-file
@(
    Echo @Echo Off
    Echo Set "Closer=1"
    Echo Set "CloseBatch=10"
    Echo Title Module Configuration
    Echo Color 80
    Echo Echo Module configuration
    Echo Echo(
    Echo Set /P "selectName=Select the name of the IncognitoModule: "
    Echo ClS
    Echo Echo Module configuration
    Echo Echo(
    Echo Set /P "keybindStart=Select the letter that will start incognito mode (CHROME): "
    Echo ClS
    Echo Echo Module configuration
    Echo Echo(
    Echo Set /P "keybindClose=Select the letter that will close CHROME: "
    Echo(
    Echo :Closerino
    Echo ClS
    Echo Echo Module configuration
    Echo Echo(
    Echo Set /P "CloseBatch=Select do you want the module to close after the chrome termination (Y / N){default NO}: "
    Echo If /I "%%CloseBatch%%" == "Y" GoTo YES
    Echo If /I "%%CloseBatch%%" == "N" GoTo NO
    Echo GoTo Closerino
    Echo(
    Echo :YES
    Echo Set "Closer=2"
    Echo(
    Echo :NO
    Echo Set "Closer=1"
    Echo ClS
    Echo Echo You selected the name %%selectName%%
    Echo Echo You selected the Keybind to start incognito mode %%keybindStart%%
    Echo Echo You selected the Keybind to close chrome %%keybindClose%%
    Echo (
    Echo    Echo @Echo Off
    Echo    Echo(
    Echo    Echo :Back
    Echo    Echo Title %%selectName%%
    Echo    Echo %%%%SystemRoot%%%%\System32\choice.exe /C %%keybindStart%%%%keybindClose%% /N
    Echo    Echo If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Close
    Echo    Echo Start "" chrome.exe --new-window --incognito "https://www.google.com"
    Echo    Echo Echo You started new Incognito window
    Echo    Echo %%%%SystemRoot%%%%\System32\timeout.exe /t 2 /NoBreak ^^^>NUL
    Echo    Echo GoTo Back
    Echo    Echo(
    Echo    Echo :Close
    Echo    Echo %%%%SystemRoot%%%%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /Im chrome.exe
    Echo ^) ^> "%%selectName%%.bat"
    Echo If /I Not "%%Closer%%" == "2" GoTo Back
    Echo %%SystemRoot%%\System32\taskkill.exe /Fi "UserName Eq %%UserName%%" /Im cmd.exe
) 1> "TempIncognitoCreator.bat"
```

Please also note that you have decided to use `Set /P`, which is potentially dangerous, if you are not implementing some method of ensuring your end user is inputting the correct data. So let's take `Set /P "selectName=Select the name of the IncognitoModule: "` for instance. If your end user was to use a module name that was invalid for a filename, you'd have issues creating `"%selectName%.bat"`. I would therefore suggest that you incorporate some validation techniques, if you want this to be more robust.

Comment: But I wanted to ask:
I don't exactly understand the grammar of your changed code when rewriting the file(I see its simpler, but because i am pretty fresh I don't understand exactly), also  why do you write a full %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /Im chrome.exe

Comment: @Penthemaker. it's simpler when you consider that `(Echo SomeString) > "output.txt"` is always the correct syntax. The only difference is that you are `echo`ing several strings. Once you understand that `>` will open a file, write to it, then close it again, you should see that if you do that for every line. the system is opening and closing the file multiple times. It's considerably more efficient to just open it once, and close it when you've finished. As for your second question, using `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe` removes any reliance on the `%PATH%` variable, which is often broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your going through the steps of creating an ancillary file in such a convoluted way. You can define default config options in variables and append new definition values to the running script when config options are modified. When Calling the config label, the most recently appended definitions will be applied:

```bat
@ECHO off
 Setlocal Enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:# Clear any existing definitions for '.' prefixed script variables
 (For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%G in ('Set "."')Do Set "%%G=") 2> nul
:# execute config label ; define default definitions ; overrides if settings modified
 CALL :config

:menu
 CLS
 Echo/[!.Exit!] Exit
 Echo/[!.Start!] Start Incognito Session
 Echo/[!.Close!] Close Incognito Session
 Echo/[!.Config!] Edit %~n0 Configuration
 For /F "Delims=" %%C in ('Choice /N /C:!.Choicelist!')Do (
  If "%%C" == "!.exit!" (
   If defined config.mod >>"%~f0" (For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%G in ('Set "." ^| Sort /R')Do Echo/Set "%%G=%%H")
   Exit /B 0
  )
  If "%%C" == "!.start!" Start "" chrome.exe --new-window -incognito
  If "%%C" == "!.close!" (
   For /F "Skip=3 Delims=" %%G in ('Tasklist.exe /FI "imagename eq chrome.exe" /FI "sessionname eq console" /FO:table')Do (
    For /F "tokens=2" %%H in ("%%G")Do Taskkill.exe /PID %%H 2> nul > nul
   )
  )
  If "%%C" == "!.config!" (
   Echo/Select Key to overide: !.Choicelist!
   For /F "Delims=" %%D in ('Choice /N /C:!.Choicelist!')Do (
    Echo/Select New Key: !.Keylist!
    For /F "Delims=" %%E in ('Choice /N /C:!.Keylist!')Do (
     For %%O in ("exit" "start" "close" "config")Do If "!.%%~O!" == "%%D" Set ".%%~O=%%E"
     Set ".Keylist=!.Keylist:%%E=%%D!"
     Set ".Choicelist=!.Choicelist:%%D=%%E!"
     Set "config.mod=_"
    )
   )
  )
 )
Goto :menu

::: SCRIPT BREAK - end of script
:config
:# Default definitions for script variables prefixed with '.' to facilitate bulk output.
 Set ".exit=Q"&Set ".Start=O"&Set ".Close=X"& Set ".Config=C"
 Set ".Keylist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST0123456789"
 For %%A in (!.Exit! !.Start! !.Close! !.Config!)Do (
  Set ".Choicelist=!.Choicelist!%%A"
  Set ".Keylist=!.Keylist:%%A=!"
 )

:# appended CONFIG Options. Last Line must end with CRLF
```

Comment: Well I just dont understand the code above, it looks so weird to me and I somehow manage to not understand the explanations, and It looks way simpler for me when i do in a way noone does

Comment: Not understanding something is fine, however not being prepared to learn when shown an approach that can avoid the issues your experience makes the excercise of asking a question somewhat redundant.
All commands have a help page to undestand their basic usage `commandname /?`.  
The `choice` command is used to select options in a safe way, `substring modification`, explained in `set /?` help output is used to mainuplate list variables used to change control key options.

Comment: `Call` is used to call a label placed at the end of the script that defines control / list variables used in the menu. `%~f0` is a metavariabe that expands to the scripts full path. `For /F` can be used to iterate over the output of commands, in the above case allowing all variables prefixed with `.` to be appended to the end of the script in the same command. `For /F` is also used to capture the literal keypress used in the `choice` command for use in substring modification.

Comment: I am prepared to learn and It just needs practise I guess, thank you for the explanation :)